# Append data frames in R dynamically

Tags: r, excel, database, dataframe

I am trying to append several data frames in R by means of a for loop but the following code wouldn't work:

```
rm(list = ls())

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     Libraries
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library("dplyr")
library("readxl")

date <- "202203"
startwave   <- 2010
endwave     <- 2018

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     Paths and Files
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
dell <- 1 
if (dell == 1) {
  computer <- "C:/Users/jj22684/"
} else {
  computer <- "C:/Users/lenovo/"
}

Main_path   <- paste(computer, "Dropbox/DATA/REGCON", sep = "")
raw_path      <- paste(computer, "Dropbox/DATA/REGCON/RAW files", sep = "")

# REGCON_PATHS

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     Import
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for (y in endwave:startwave) {
    FIRMCAtemp <- read_excel(paste(raw_path, "/Datos_totales_", y, "_REGCON.xlsx", sep = ""))
    assign(toString(y),y)
    FIRMCAtemp$year <- y
    assign(paste("FIRMCA", y, sep = ""),FIRMCAtemp)
}

for (y in startwave:endwave) {
    FIRMCAtemp <- rbind(FIRMCAtemp,paste("FIRMCA", y, sep = ""))
}
```

I have also tried using the sym() function it doesn't make the trick either.

I would be very thankful if someone could give me some ideas on how to proceed.

KR
Ruben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `lapply` to read your XL files into a list and to use `dplyr::bind_rows` to bind them into one df.

Using some fake example data:

```r
# Create exammple files
rawpath <- tempdir()

writexl::write_xlsx(mtcars, file.path(rawpath, "Datos_totales_2010_REGCON.xlsx"))
writexl::write_xlsx(mtcars, file.path(rawpath, "Datos_totales_2011_REGCON.xlsx"))

startwave   <- 2010
endwave     <- 2011

lapply(endwave:startwave, function(y) {
  x <- readxl::read_excel(paste0(rawpath, "/Datos_totales_", y, "_REGCON.xlsx"))
  x$year <- y
  x
}) |> 
  dplyr::bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 64 × 12
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  year
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4  2011
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4  2011
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1  2011
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1  2011
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2  2011
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1  2011
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4  2011
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2  2011
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2  2011
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4  2011
#> # … with 54 more rows
```